# Moodle Mobile Hybrid App stucks at "connect to moodle" screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework, moodle-mobile

I have build moodle mobile custom app for my website. I am successful in running the app in the browser.

```
Command
cordova serve
```

But when I am building this app for android, It stucks at the screen "Connect to moodle" . Inspite of giving the correct url of my moodle website the app halts at this screen only.
Please find a screenshot of the issue in the attachments below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you haven't installed the plugin cordova-plugin-network-information. If you run the app using Ionic/Cordova CLI you need to install all the plugins and platforms. You can do so running "ionic state restore". Please follow the steps detailed in here:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2